# Getting twitter data in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, twitter, twitter-oauth

i want to get 90 day retweets, mention in C#.I used [this](https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=kool_aid_wino) ,but it doesn't work for 90 days and return only one tweet.Anyone who had done just type of work before,
Thanks in meekness

Comment: Hi @Mentor; if you could please show a sample of your code then it will be easier for answerers to see what you've done and make suggestions. As an aside, have you looked at the open source libraries here? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/open-source-examples

Comment: @dash yes I have looked there.Actually I dont want to use OAuth (consumer key ,secret key) etc...

Comment: @dash Please open the Link I have provided then you will came to know

Comment: I don't get what you want so you can look at the link to see if one of those command solves your trouble https://dev.twitter.com/tags/retweets?page=1

Comment: @renamr this require OAuth rite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get retweets, see those methods :

GET http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweeted_by_me.json for tweets retweeted by the authenticated user (documentation here).

Answer (score 1):

The REST method you used is for getting details about a user defined by its username (`screen_name` parameter). It returns the user.

To get retweets, see those methods :

- `GET http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweeted_by_me.json` for tweets retweeted by the authenticated user (documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweeted_by_me)).
- `GET http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweeted_by_user.json` for tweets retweeted by a random user (documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweeted_by_user)).

For mentions, use `GET http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/mentions.json` (documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/mentions)).

However, it returns the most recent tweets. 90 days retweets and mentions might not be enough recent to be retrieved.

Comment: How do I count the total number of retweets for any user?

Comment: A timeline is a list, an array of tweets. I let you find how to do to count them. ;-)

Moreover, you can specify how many tweets you want with the count parameter. It has to be <= 200.

Comment: I am talking about tweet,not retweets.How can I count number of retweets for a user ID/

Comment: A retweet is a tweet with a field called "retweeted_status" (in Twitter replies) that contains the tweet that has been retweeted. So you can count how many tweets in your list are in this case. But all the tweets downloaded with the 2 REST methods I gave you are supposed to be retweets so the number of retweets in the list is the size of the list.

Comment: still i am not getting it,which call should be used to get the list and the calculate?

Comment: For the call, the first is for the authenticated user and the second for all user. RTFM. 
For the calculate, you only need your skills in C# to know how many objects in a list get a criteria (here retweets of a user). 
I cannot help you more.

Comment: You are not getting me,in the non-authenticatred call we give a count variable which is  <=200,What if the person have more than 200 tweets? I want to get complete timeline from a user

Comment: I dont want to get retweet by a person,i want to get the retweet did by the "followings",that appears as tweet on your account..Please help me with this..(I want to calculate Reyweet to You)

Comment: GET http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweeted_to_user.json method is yours ( https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweeted_to_me ).

Comment: this method also needs a count,i have checked that. <=100.I mean i want to calulate the total retweets,and I am giving the number of retweets as input,this seem useless for me